# window.open not working parse URL truncated

Tags: javascript, php, url, window.open

I'm trying to get a link to open as a new window in PHP, I tried the following and a few variations, yet for some reason the links stops in `javascript:void(window.open(`
Any idea? Could it be something wrong with the `'""'`?

```
$html .= '<a class="ficha_partido_popup" href="javascript:void(window.open("/servicios/deporte/partidos/fichapartido_'.$filaPartido["partidocod"].'.html"))" rel="nofollow" title="Ver Ficha del partido"><img src="/imagenes/ficha.png" alt="Ver la ficha del partido" /></a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To make it simple, divide it into 2 lines**

```
$window_link = 'window.open("/file_path/filename_'.$filaPartido["partidocod"].'.html")';
$html .= '<a href="javascript:void( ' . $window_link . ' )" >Any link</a>';
```

**OR**

```
$link = $filaPartido["partidocod"];
$html .= <<<HTML
<a href="javascript:void( window.open('/file_path/filename_{$link}.html') )" >Any link</a>
HTML;
```

Comment: Second option works like a charm! Thanks you very much!!! Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes:

```
$html .= '<a class="ficha_partido_popup" href="javascript:void(window.open(\"/servicios/deporte/partidos/fichapartido_'.$filaPartido["partidocod"].'.html\"))" rel="nofollow" title="Ver Ficha del partido"><img src="/imagenes/ficha.png" alt="Ver la ficha del partido" /></a>';
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply... I tried this solution, but online result is: <a class="ficha_partido_popup" href="javascript:void(window.open(" servicios="" deporte="" partidos="" fichapartido_18721.html"));"="" rel="nofollow" title="Ver Ficha del partido"><img src="/imagenes/ficha.png" alt="Ver la ficha del partido"></a>
Any idea?

Comment: Depends what "online" tool you used, there could be all sorts of escaping going on. Use it in your own environment.

Answer (score 1):

- You're using `'` (single quote) to create the string in PHP.
- You're using `"` (double quote) to create the string in Javascript.

Now, you're saying `href="...window.open("...")"`. The issue is that you're trying to nest `"` within `"` and that just breaks it all. So the first double quote inside window.open ends up being the closing double quote for href and the rest of the string just becomes invalid in javascript.

To fix this, you can replace nested double quotes with single quotes and say `href="...window.open('...')"`, except that you can't since if you use single quotes here, you'll end up breaking things in PHP since you're using single quotes to form the string in PHP.

So, use single nested quotes but escape them, like this -

```
href="...window.open(\'...\')"
```

So, your code will now become -

```
$html .= '<a class="ficha_partido_popup" href="javascript:void(window.open(\'/servicios/deporte/partidos/fichapartido_'.$filaPartido["partidocod"].'.html\'))" rel="nofollow" title="Ver Ficha del partido"><img src="/imagenes/ficha.png" alt="Ver la ficha del partido" /></a>';
```